# How can I get the payload inside of a node from a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, class, nested

```
template<class T> class CRevList
{
public:
//...constructor, destructor, etc;
  class Node //nested class   
  {
  public:
   friend class CRevList;

    Node() {m_next = 0;  m_prev = 0;}
    Node(const T &t) {m_payload = t;  m_next = 0;  m_prev = 0;}

    T Data() {return m_payload;}
    const T Data() const {return m_payload;}

    private:

      Node    *m_next;
      Node    *m_prev;
      T       m_payload;
  };
private: //for original class
  Node    *m_head, *m_tail;             // Head node
  unsigned size;
};
```

I've made many attempts to get the payload of the nodes from original doubly linked class unfortunately I get errors. most like:

```
       error: request for member 'Data' in 'Temp1', which is of non-class type 'CRevList<int>::Node*'
```

I must be messing something up with pointers or relationships between the two classes.

I've tried:

```
  //Find a node with the specified key
  const Node *Find(const T &t) const {  }
  Node *Find(const T &t) {
    Node * Temp1 = m_head;

    while(m_tail != Temp1){
            if(Temp1.Data() == t){
                    return Temp1;
            }

            Temp1 = Temp1->m_next;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Along with timrau's answer below, you're *probably* going to want to change that `const T Data() const` to be `const T& Data() const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Temp1` is of type `Node *`. Thus, you should call `Temp1->Data()` instead of `Temp1.Data()`.

Comment: Wow I feel silly. I've had this error before, too. Thanks for pointing it out to me. what is     -> called?